# Primitive of an analytic function - Proof verification

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Check out the proof for the following corollary. 
[image]

This is only the first part of the proof and I have a issue with this. $F(z)$ is defined by integrating $f$ along a line segment. But isn't it necessary for it to be defined on a general path so that it confirms that it is well defined? I know for a fact that F is well defined using the Cauchy-Goursat theorem but this appears in the text before the general Cauchy Goursat Thoerem and this uses only the Triangle version of it. This confuses me and hope someone could help me out. Thanks

**EDIT** The following says that F is well defined means it is path independent
[image]

Comment: May I ask what book is this from?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that you don't really want to prove that the integral is path-independent. You **define** your function $F$ as an integral over this particular line segment. Now, you prove that $F'(z) = f(z)$. So, by definition, $F$ is the primitive of $f$.

The fact that this integral exists should be clear from the analycity of $f$, which implies that it is continuous along any line segment (or curve) in $D$ and this line segment (or curve) is a compact.

Comment: The closed curve's interior should be contained in the open set in which the analytic function is defined on otherwise it is not path independent

Comment: Thanks for the edit but you should mention that the interior of the closed curve is contained in the domain of f otherwise this is not true

Comment: I think that I am using the Cauchy theorem that is not yet proven... that might be a bigger problem...

Comment: As I said I want to prove this without using the general Cauchy Goursat theorem

Comment: please check the addition to my question

Answer (score 1):

This proof is okay.  It is defining $F(z)$ using a specific path, namely the unique line segment between $z$ and $z_*$.  This definition is unambiguous.  There may a problem with something else in the proof, if the author uses path independence which is not yet proven, but at this point, there is no problem, and $F(z)$ is well defined.

Edit: Maybe this will aid understanding.  It's slightly misleading for the author to write the integral using $z$ and $z_*$ ( ie. endpoints ) rather than saying the integral is 
$$
\int_{\gamma}f(z)dz
$$
where $\gamma $ is the unique line segment joining $z$ and $z_*$.  Using the endpoints kind of makes it sound implicit that the integral is defined using path independence, which it is not. Does this help?

Comment: How can you say F is well defined?

Comment: @Heisenberg because there is a unique line segment joining $z$ and $z_*$ and it lies in $D$ because $D$ is star shaped and $z_*$ is a star-center.  You don't need path independence yet.

Comment: Thanks but the path independence is not proved in this and I don't think Cauchy Goursat can be used to do this. How can I go forward with this?

Comment: @Heisenberg You don't need path independence or Cauchy-Goursat.  There's nothing about path independence being used.  At no point ( so far ) does the author say that $F(z)$ can be evaluated along a different path than the straight line between $z$ and $z_*$.  That would use path independence.  At this point though, path independence may be false!  Note that we could define $F(z)$ this way even if $f$ were just integrable.  Then path independence might fail!  But $F(z)$ would still be well defined.

Comment: I see I was under the impression that when defining F a general pth should be used. However this maybe OK for this but if we consider a general domain instead of a star like domain we cannot simply a line segment right? that is where I got confused

Comment: @Heisenberg Correct, if it's not a star-shaped domain, then the line segment may not lie within $D$ and $F(z)$ would not be well-defined.

Comment: Callus, I am sorry to comment on this again but I on a text which said F is well defined means that it is not path dependent. Confused again

Comment: Check my question I added that part from the book

Comment: "well-defined" means that any choices inherent in the definition are irrelevant.  At this point in the book, the definition depends on choice of a path, so path independence is necessary to make that definition well-defined.   In the original passage you quoted, the $F$ was defined as an integral on a specific path (namely the straight line), so there is no choice in the definition, so it is automatically well-defined

Comment: So say I want to prove that every analytic function has a primitive in an open disk. How would you define F? Line segment?Or a general path?

Comment: I would let $F(z)$ be defined as the integral along the straight line from the center of the disk to $z$.  This avoids any choices.  Note that a disk is star-shaped, so this is the same as in that proof.

Comment: Why the center and not an arbitrary point?

Comment: To avoid having to show that it's well defined.  But any fixed point would work, because any point in a disk is a star center